# how to have an else block execute only once in a for loop

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a `for` loop which is used to compare user login details to launch the next screen of an application.

If the user-entered fields are successfully matched to data in an `ArrayList` returned from a database the program launches next screen -- if they are not matched an error message is outputted to the user using `JOptionPane`.

My problem is the error message is outputted for every iteration of the `for` loop but I want the message to only be displayed once.

```
  //if name or password are NOT left blank proceed with the check otherwise output error message in the text area
    if (!name.equals("") && !password.equals("")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < passwords.size(); i++) {
            if (name.equals(userNames.get(i)) && (password.equals(passwords.get(i)))) {
                myHomeGUI.setVisible(true);
                break;
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry, no user recognized with those credentials\nPlease try again");
            }
        }//end for loop 
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry, no fields can be left blank");
    }//end
```

Comment: So add a break statement after the message;

Comment: tryed that , if i have a break statement after message in the else it wont work. For example if the 3rd position of my arraylist for userNames is david, and the user enters john which is not in the array list it will break out of the loop and never get as far as david and so never evaluate to True

Comment: I would think about changing the userNames/passwords thing. Why do you have two Lists? wouldnt it be better to have (for example) a (Hash)Map<String,String> with username/password in it?  Then you dont need to go through in a loop. just compare the password against the map.get(username)

Comment: thanks ,  I havent worked with hash Maps before but i will look into it, this is a college project im working on

Answer (score 6):

This is happening because you put the `else condtion` in your `loop` which executed in every `Iteration`

Try this :

```
boolean isValid=false; 
for (int i = 0; i < passwords.size(); i++) {
            if (name.equals(userNames.get(i)) && (password.equals(passwords.get(i)))) {
                myHomeGUI.setVisible(true);
                isValid=true;
                break;
            }
 }//end for loop 
 if(!isValid) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry, no user recognized with those credentials\nPlease try again");
}
```

**Update**

As @Joelblade suggested , you can also transfer this authentication logic into a seperate method

```
public boolean  isAuthenticationPassed(String userName,String password){
              return true; // When Login Successfull
              or 
              return false; // When Login unsuccessfull 
    }
```

then check in your LoginController

```
if(isAuthenticationPassed){
  // Do whatever you want to do 
}
else{
//Return to Login Page with error / or show Dialog Box
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much the structure I would use. You can even move the whole for loop into a method (boolean authenticateUser(name, password) ) and do: if (!authenticateUser(name, password))

Comment: @Joeblade , I am a big supporter of modular Approach , but was in a hurry So haven't provided much suggestion .Adding this suggestion in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As said in a comment above: you also could use a Map instead two Lists

```
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("john", "1234");
    map.put("test", "asdf");

    String name = "test";
    String password = "asdf";


     //if name or password are NOT left blank proceed with the check otherwise output error message in the text area
    if (!name.equals("") && !password.equals("")) {

            if(map.get(name)!=null && map.get(name).equals(password))
                myHomeGUI.setVisible(true);
                break;
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry, no user recognized with those credentials\nPlease try again");
           }         
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry, no fields can be left blank");

    }//end
```

Comment: One should never expose `Passwords( or other confidential/sensitive information)` like this in source Code . It's bad practice

Comment: you are of course absolutely right! RoRo88 hasnt used a Map before, so i just wanted him to show how you insert data.

Answer (score 0):

If you refactor your code up into more logical parts it will be much easier to code and understand, for example:

```
if (name.equals("") || password.equals("")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry, no fields can be left blank");
} else if(doesUserExist(name, password)) {
    myHomeGUI.setVisible(true);
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry, no user recognized with those credentials\nPlease try again");
}

// ... new method

private boolean doesUserExist(String name, String password) {
    for (int i = 0; i < passwords.size(); i++) {
        if (name.equals(userNames.get(i)) && (password.equals(passwords.get(i)))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```